# How do I rename *.faa filenames for an expression located inside each file in [brackets]?

Tags: command-line, rename, filename

I would like to rename the filenames *.faa (a typical name is protein-176.faa) for a name that is located inside each .faa file in brackets [Escherichia coli DSM123].

For example the file **protein-44.faa** includes the first lines:

```
>ABI60899.1 Multidrug resistance protein B [Granulibacter bethesdensis CGDNIH1]
MVRQGRPSQSREQEDISEPGTQGRGWMQARHVHHWRFHHRRAVHKDLMTQPRSSRPVSSRILALIVSAALFMELMDGTIL
ATALPQMAQSFDVAPLQMSVALTAYLLSLAVFIPASGWMADRFGSRRIFMGAIALFVTGSMVCGMANALPEMVIARLVQG
AGGAMMVPVGRLLLLRNVPRHELVSAIAWMTIPATLGPVLGPPVGGFLTTWLSWRWIFYINLPIGLIGMGLAARFVPNVT
EAELRPLDVKGLLLSGTALASLLWAMETLGRGPSGTDGMALSSAAILTLIGLGSGWLYLRHSRTIPHPILNPMLMRIRTF
RLSVLGGACSRVVAGAMPFLLPMTMQLGMGMSAAESGSLTFVGAAGSLLIRPWAAGILRRFGFRRVMIWNGALSSTAVLL
CATFQPSWPHGWFFLVLAPAGLFQALQFIAYNTIAYADVPRERMSEATSFYTTFQQMTLSAGICIAGISVSLSMLAGPRT
QPDMTDFATGFVTIATISALAILCASRLNSTDGQDLSRKA
>ABI60900.1 Uroporphyrinogen decarboxylase [Granulibacter bethesdensis CGDNIH1]
MNKPILRVLRGEALPVPPVWLMRQAGRYLPEYREVRAKAGSFLGLATHPEWAAEVTLQPIRRFGMDAAILFSDILMLPWA
```

and should be renamed to **Granulibacter bethesdensis CGDNIH1.faa**

I have hundreds of files with suffix .faa in a folder and I am bored of trying this manually. There must be a way to do it quickly and elegantly.

The solution provided here does not work: https://www.biostars.org/p/444704/

I appreciate your help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you linked simply picks out the first line of the file (`head-1`), selects the first space-delimited string using `cut`, and then removes the FASTA header marker `>` using `tr`.

If you want to do something more complicated, you will need to modify the pipeline - for example using `sed`:

```
$ for f in *.faa; do echo mv --no-clobber -- "$f" "$(sed -E 's/.*\[([^]]*)\]/\1.faa/;q' "$f")"; done
mv --no-clobber -- protein-44.faa Granulibacter bethesdensis CGDNIH1.faa
```

Remove the `echo` once you are satisfied that it is doing the right thing.

Comment: Works very nice. Thank you steeldriver! :)